# Windows Phone 8 emulator in Visual studio 2013 RC not running properly in my Windows 8.1 system?

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-phone-8-emulator

I have Hyper V enabled Windows 8.1 system but when I try to debug my windows app in Emulator it shows error message as follows:

**[image: I have Visual Studio 2013 RC version!!]**

Comment: Did you restart the system after enabling the Hypervisor? I remember there being issues if one does not reboot.

Comment: can you tell me how to enable this?

Comment: The hypervisor can be enabled and disabled from services.msc

Comment: Still it is showing same problem error message and emulator can't run.

Answer (score 0):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/b06cc9f2-aa5e-4cb3-9df1-0c273e1dfd68/wp8-emulator-xde-troubleshooting-tips?forum=wptools
this need to be followed for this case specially:
Workaround: disable all third party drivers and applications which may be interfering with the virtual network used by the Emulator to communicate with Visual Studio. This may include:

```
Antivirus applications (which hook into the network stack)
Network monitoring tools
Network logging tools
Other system monitoring software
```

Another possible approach, short of uninstalling the product(s) in question (and requesting the product developer to release an updated version), here is a possible workaround:

1. Launch the “Network Connections” manager (from the home screen, type in “View Network Connections”, It will be listed under Settings)
2. Right click on the adapter named: “vEthernet (Internal Ethernet Port Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch)”
3. For that adapter, the only items that should be checked under “This connection uses the following items:” should be:

   Client for Microsoft Networks
   QoS Packet Scheduler
   File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks
   Microsoft LLDP Protocol Driver
   Link-Layer Topology Discovery Mapper I/O Driver
   Link-Layer Topology Discovery Responder
   Internet Protocol Version 6 (TCP/IPv6)
   Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)
4. All other items should be unchecked.